# Is there anyway to change the placeholder style of year, month, and day separators (/) in a date input field?

Tags: css, date, input, safari, placeholder

I do not like the way a browser styles placeholder text for a date input field. The forward slash character(/) is in a normal black color and the year, month, and day values are a light gray. I want to make the whole thing light gray.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your placeholder text looks like input text, just style the placeholder like this:

```
input #yourInputId::placeholder{color:#acacac;font-family: yourFontFamily;}
```

You can see the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder

> **The ::placeholder CSS pseudo-element represents the placeholder text in an  or  element.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).